# How to go through labels which are struct items at Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uilabel

I have a struct with labels;

```
struct InfoLabels {
    var info0 = UILabel()
    var info1 = UILabel()
    var info2 = UILabel()
}

var infoLabels: [InfoLabels] = []
```

When needed we are adding new labels to show on screen.

Increasing label numbers like this and add them at to view.
I dont show setting locations etc. of labels here to keep it simple.

```
infoLabels.append(InfoLabels())
```

When I did not need them, that was the way removing them from view like this;

```
for k in 0..< infoLabels.count {
    infoLabels[k].info0.removeFromSuperview()
    infoLabels[k].info1.removeFromSuperview()
    infoLabels[k].info2.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

But when I go deeper to my prototype app, number of info labels increased and removing them
from view like this become unfeasible.

I need to find a way go through info labels like info0, info1,..., infon.
I saw using mirror usage to go though struct items but it did not worked for UILabel;

This is not working;

```
let mirroredLabel = Mirror(reflecting: infoLabels)
    
    
for item in mirroredLabel.children  
        item.label.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
struct InfoLabels {
    var count: Int
    var labels: [UILabel] = []

    init(_ count: Int) {
        self.count = count 
        labels = Array(repeating: UILabel, count: count)
    }
}
```

and then

```
infoLabels.append(InfoLabels(3))
```

for deletions use

```
infoLabels.labels.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Comment: I think that will work too but label names must be different because when we look at the code we need to understand what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found the answer but I found mistake I made it works like that;

```
for k in 0..< infoLabels.count {

   let mirroredLabel = Mirror(reflecting: infoLabels[k])       
     for label in mirroredLabel.children  {
        (label.value as! UILabel).removeFromSuperview()
    }

  }
```

Comment: Is there a `removeFromSuperview()` function in `AnyObject` type?

Comment: It works, I tried. Xcode suggested adding any object.

Comment: Well, it passes the compilation, for sure, but it doesn't jump to the definition of the function. That's weird.

Comment: It is removing labels from view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection for the `InfoLabels` struct. So you code might look like this:

```
infoLabels.forEach {
    let mirroredLabel = Mirror(reflecting: $0)
    mirroredLabel.children.forEach { child in
        (child.value as? UILabel)?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```